# Vector overwriting object pointers

Tags: c++

Everytime I call this method, The information is overwritten. If I call this function with `name = "greg"` then it will cout greg, If I then input "carl" it will cout carlcarl.  The constructor is empty, and group and _groups are declared in the header.

I've been stuck on this for about 6 hours and I'm at a loss. Can someone explain to me how to fix this? It's not shown, but "group" is an object pointer. I'm taking this as a college course and its pretty much self-taught, I have to follow strict instructions on what to use and what not to use. I can't use strings.

```
void GroupDB::addGroup(char* name)
{

    group = new GroupInfo(name, _nextGid++);
    _groups.push_back(group);
    for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        cout << (*_groups.at(i)).getGroupName();
    }
    _size++;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit, but it should be (*_groups.at(i)).getGroupName();
edit: Thank you :)

Comment: You simply click on "edit". You also forgot to post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Going to need to see more code.  A short complete example would be best.  We have no idea what your constructor does, how the vector is declared, etc.  Based on this code all I see is a possible memory leak since you create 2 items and only push back one of them.

Comment: If you're using `vector`, you really should also use `string`. That would save you a lot of problems. Also don't use raw pointers if you can help it.

Comment: I'd guess that `GroupInfo` stores the pointer you passed it (instead of copying the string), and you are calling this function multiple times with the same pointer. (That is: you're not calling the function with `"greg"`, you are calling it with `name` being some buffer containing `greg`, and then you call it again with `name` being the same buffer whose contents have been changed)

Comment: don't use vector with (new).  You are asking for a memory leak.  You need to use a smart pointer.  (shared_ptr<>, auto_ptr<>), depending on the version of c++ you're using.

Comment: You're allocating (and leaking) an extra `GroupInfo` every time this function is called. You're also double-incrementing `nextGid` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Matt, you are on the money. and Gadi I haven't learned about those. How can I fix this Johnathan?

Comment: @Gadi suggesting to use `auto_ptr` in a `std::vector` is worse than using raw pointers in a `std::vector`

Comment: @Judjohn Give more information about the class.

Comment: @Gadi `auto_ptr` cannot go in a `vector` because it does not behave properly on copy-assignment or copy-construction

Answer (score 0):

It sound's like you're storing the `name` pointer itself, which points to a temporary array that's invalidated at some point after this function returns. Instead, you want to store a more persistent copy of the string data. Use `std::string` not `char*` to store strings. If you "can't use strings" as a condition of the exercise, then you'll need to allocate an array to store the string data in, just as `std::string` would.

In general, don't use pointers unless you really need to. I doubt you want to be messing around with `new` here, but should rather store `GroupInfo` objects directly in the vector (or whatever `_groups` is).

Comment: Not quite true.   The pointer passed will be in scope of the caller.   It will be invalidated when the calling scope is exited.

Comment: @Rob: Sorry, I was a bit vague, and might have implied that the function return itself invalidates the pointer (as it would if it pointed to a local variable). I just meant it was invalidated at some point after the function returns, leaving the stored pointer dangling.